# How can i set query params in rxjs ajax?

Tags: reactjs, ajax, rxjs

I am using rxjs in my react app. I have following options in my ajax rxjs

```
const options = {
    url,
    method,
    timeout:100000,
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      'subscription-key': 'xxx'
    },
  };
  if (method === "post" || method === "put") {
    options.body = request;
  }


  console.log('options', options);
  return ajax(options, {param: 42});
};
```

i can't find a way so automatically to insert query params on my base url in my ajax request

i tried adding in options `params` property

```
const options = {
    url,
    method,
    timeout:100000,
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      'subscription-key': 'xxx'
    },
    params: {page: 1}
  };
```

so it will make request like

domain.com?page=1

but without success. It only takes the base url

how can i make this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in the `AjaxConfig` interface ([source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/65de22958f1b4cbf2b7a0de44be89a5bbf36ff90/src/internal/ajax/types.ts#L70)), there is no way to set the query other than by extending the requested URL.

You will have to add your queries the following way:

```
const options = {
  url: `${url}?page=1`,
  ...
```